# Editing the Metadata of HttpRequest for Akka GRPC Authentication

Tags: scala, httprequest, akka-http, akka-grpc

Akka-grpc documentation provides a basic [example](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-grpc/current/server/akka-http.html) of adding authentication through Akka-http.

At the end, it suggests that the authentication result can be embedded in the `metadata` of the `HttpRequest` and can be accessible in the grpc service methods as the metadata argument, with proper configuration enabling the `powerAPI`, in the `conf` file.

Also, on the [details](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-grpc/current/server/details.html) page, it says that metadata is for providing access to request headers in the grpc service interfaces; which makes sense. It also provides an example of how a `Metadata` instance can be built with `MetadataBuilder`.

Now, the question is this:

How can I pass the constructed metadata object with information on the authenticated user to the HttpRequest? Am I supposed to use the `addHeader` method or another one?